# Stacking effects & powerups in UI | Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, game-development

How could I make it so, for example, if only one thing is on it will move to the first slot, I think you know what I mean... So how could I make this?1

I thought about using arrays but I don't understand how.

This is my code currently, rn it just shows and hides but doesnt move them so there just a gap.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text myText;
    public GameObject Player;
    public GameObject SugarIcon;
    public GameObject DashIcon;
    public GameObject JumpIcon;
    public GameObject ShieldIcon;
    private string dashreadystring;
    private string doublejumpstring;
    private string triplejumpstring;
    private string shieldbuffstring;
    private int iconamount = 0;
    
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        PlayerScript PlayerScript = Player.GetComponent<PlayerScript>();
        bool dashready = PlayerScript.canDash;
        float sugarbuff = PlayerScript.sugarbuffactive;
        int airJumpCount = PlayerScript.airJumpCount;
        int airJumpCountMax = PlayerScript.airJumpCountMax;
        bool canDoubleJump = PlayerScript.canDoubleJump;
        bool shieldon = PlayerScript.shieldon;
        float score = Player.transform.position.x;

        // If Dash is ready, show icon, if not, hide it.
        if (dashready == true)
        {
            DashIcon.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            DashIcon.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
        }

        // If Sugarbuff is active, show icon, if not, hide it.
        if (sugarbuff == 1.5)
        {
            SugarIcon.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            SugarIcon.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
        }

        // If can jump, 
        if ((airJumpCount < airJumpCountMax) | ((canDoubleJump) && (sugarbuff == 1.5f)))
        {
            JumpIcon.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            JumpIcon.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
        }
        if (shieldon)
        {
            ShieldIcon.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ShieldIcon.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

How could I make this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your icons are children of a parent container that uses a HorizontalLayoutGroup component, it will automatically line up your icons horizontally (use VerticalLayoutGroup or GridLayoutGroup to autoalign in different patterns).

Then, if you disable the gameObject of the icons, they will disappear. The HorizontalLayoutGroup will rearrange the remaining icons in the way I think you want. When you reenable the icon, it will be reinserted into the horizontal layout.

Notes:

1. You are currently disabling the Renderer Component on the gameObject. This does make the object invisible, but it still exists and takes up space. Instead, disable the gameObject for the icon itself (SugarIcon.enabled = false).  Hopefully the Icon objects are just images, and have no scripts/logic on them, but if so, you'll need to decouple that.
2. It looks like you're using GetComponent() calls many times every frame.  Don't do this -- GetComponent() calls have a pretty big overhead.  Instead, call it once, when you initialize your manager, and then cache the result.  This will save a ton of processing.

// Call GetComponent() and cache the reference one time (when you initialize the objects).

```
Renderer sugarIconRenderer = SugarIcon.GetComponent<Renderer>();
```

// Call the cached reference every frame when you need it.

```
sugarIconRenderer.enabled = false;
```